# make an absolute div hidden when something outside of it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code for the function that runs when a button is clicked in my site:

```
function shadow() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("dim").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("dim").onclick="document.getElementById('dim','overlay').style.visibility='hidden'";
}
```

With overlay being the overlay div that I want to be re-hide-able, and dim being the lower z-index dimmer over the entire page when the function runs.
The third line is my attempt at making it so that when an area outside of the overlay is clicked, the dim and overlay go away - help on that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`onclick` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) expects a function reference, not a string. In addition, the `getElementById` method only accepts a single `id` parameter, which means that only the first element `id` that you passed to it would be selected.

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you want something like this ([live example](https://jsfiddle.net/k5ds8wwg/)):

```
function shadow() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var dim = document.getElementById('dim');

  overlay.style.visibility = 'visible';
  dim.style.visibility = 'visible';

  dim.onclick = function() {
    overlay.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    dim.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  };
}
```

Alternatively, you could also add a click event listener to `document` and then determine whether `event.target` is the `#overlay` element.

For instance, the following would work ([live example](https://jsfiddle.net/ayLec0f7/)):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var dim = document.getElementById('dim');

  if (event.target !== overlay && !event.target.closest('#overlay')) {
    overlay.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    dim.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});
```